# Calling Class in C#

Tags: c#, sql, class

I am developing a series of processes in C# which reuse the same SQL code. Below is an example of a Class I created for the SQL Connection to my test database. Question: how to do I call the Class in my process? I have tried a couple of things however, I get the below errors

Errors:

```
SQLHelperCode.FirstConnect is a 'type'  which is not valid in the given context.
Only Assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

Class FirstConnect

```
public class FirstConnect
{
    public FirstConnect()
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        string path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data";
        const string dbName = "datadetail";
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection("user id=TestUser;" +
                                     "server=TestData\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                                     "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                     "connection timeout=30");

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Want to call the FirstConnect in this code:

```
protected override void OnBarUpdate()
{
    accountName = Account.Name.ToString();

    if (accountName == 'Test1234')
    {
        //Call FirstConnect here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Instantiate the class and invoke the method like so: FirstConnect myThing = new FirstConnect(); myThing.DoSomething. The code you have provided above does not have a method on the class to call.

Comment: replace 
//Call FirstConnect here. 
with
new FirstConnect();
And make sure you close your connection

Answer (score 5):

This line defines the class

```
public class FirstConnect
 {
```

This line defines the constuctor

```
    public FirstConnect()
      {
```

The following will define a variable of type FirstConnect and then call the constructor to create it (I made it two lines to be explicit)

```
FirstConnect fc;
fc  = new FirstConnect();
```

Typically you'd then want to have method that actually does something with the object

e.g.

```
SomeOtherObject varaibleName = fc.GetSomeData(accountName);
```

Answer (score 1):

`FirstConnect fc = new FirstConnect();`

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but just a large comment...

When using classes that implement `IDisposable` like `SqlConnection` does, they should be used like so:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("user id=TestUser;server=TestData\\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=yes;connection timeout=30"))
{
   //... do work ... 
}
```

Comment: What you wrote is true but doesn't apply here. conn is a field on FirstConnect so the scope of conn can't be constrained to a using block. So FirstConnect should either implement IDisposable or be refactored so that it has connectionString field that gets used as you suggest in each method that uses it.